# symfony - two login form for admin and user

Tags: php, symfony

I have User Entity that has `isAdmin` property. when this property is 1 that means this user is Admin.
So, I created the login form for all users that log in from it.

```
        user_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username
```

but I want separate login page for user `isAdmin` property is 1.
I need to create Admin Entity and another provider? or have a solution that checks `isAdmin` property before login?

Comment: If you want to code this manually I'd look at using security roles which is built into Symfony's framework. http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the FOS UserBundle? Simple implementation together with user roles, maybe a better solution for your problem. You can check if a user is a admin or a normal user and put restrictions in the pages.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The FOS User Bundle is not working on Symfony 4 with flex. Also you often have to wait for updates. Symfony is a very good framework where you can implement a lot of stuff you need in daily business easy. So get your hrad out of the dependencies and start coding ;)